# What is the latency for WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

So WebRTC allows you to connect clients together directly without going through the server.

I'm trying to figure out what the latency would be?

Of course it would be less than with having a server, because there's less distance that has to be traveled.

But say for example that the two WebRTC clients happen to be in my house and connected to the same network. Will WebRTC know to just communicate over LAN, or will it have to go out to the public internet?

If for example, they are both connected to 4G in the same area, would it only have to go as far as the 4G antenna or whatever?

So basically are there any shortcuts?

Comment: If it can discover a path using the local LAN, it should use that.

Comment: @deceze That's great to know! :D Thanks

Comment: 90% of connections have an average RTT of below 100ms which is
good for real-time communication, as per the callstats.io metrics report 

https://www.callstats.io/hubfs/pdf/industry%20reports/WebRTC-Metrics-Report-2017-03.pdf

Comment: Another cool feature is that you can decide how much latency you are willing to tolerate (but this has tradeoffs). If you opt for less latency you may experience more loss, you can read about it here https://discourse.wicg.io/t/hint-attribute-in-webrtc-to-influence-underlying-audio-video-buffering/4038

Comment: @SeanDuBois As long as it's typically faster than tcp with a server I'm happy :)